# Odometry - 4ws quasiomnidirectional - Trigonometry - Strange behaviour

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, base-odometry, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Iam trying to make odometry work on a four wheel steering quasiomnidirectional base. Its losely based on pr2 trigonometry. The Problem that I encounter is that everything works except Angular_Z without any Linear_X or _Y. In that case the odometry frame twists opposite to reality. I also tried another approach (different math) but the same strange result. Anybody else encountered something like this before? Any suggestions how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343066/odometry---4ws-quasiomnidirectional---trigonometry---strange-behaviour/) by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 574 on 2020-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. It was my "smart" base-controller that was the issue.

EDIT: More exact, I had it decide to invert linear(wheel) if the desired steerangle was bigger then PI/2 and adjust the steeringangle accordingly. This worked with other poses because all the wheels made this move but in the case of twist only 2 out of 4 wheels made this move. I think it might have been the covariance matrix that somehow saw this as an error and started mixing things up. Will ask that question in another post.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2020-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-02-05**:
EDIT: It wasnt the "smart" base-controller. ANSWER see: https://answers.ros.org/question/343104/odometry-4ws-quasiomnidirectional-covariance_matrix/